# UIView horizontal bar animation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uianimation

I am working on this animation where a number will be received every second and progress bar has to fill or go down based on the double value.

I have created the views and have added all the views in the UIStackView. Also made the outlet collection for all the views. (sorting them by the tag and making them round rect).

I can loop the views and change their background color but trying to see if there is a better way to do it. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This way isn't terrible. UIStackView is very helpful for things like this. You could very easily make this shorter if you were in a vertically compact view. The other way would be to use core graphics to draw whole thing and fill the layer up from behind. It would be lighter weight, more complex programming, and less flexible. There are always trade offs.

Comment: I agree with Allen. This is not bad but i would probably go with Core Graphics but that takes math and work and this is finished and unless you want to optimize i probably would stick with this. I would say that you might be able to quickly do it with CAReplicatorLayer as well.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys Thanks for the comment. I've enough time so i want to do it right. Going to spend some time in learning the core graphics. Please do share if you have any good tutorials. Thanks

Comment: @agibson007 Thanks for the comment. I've enough time so i want to do it right. Going to spend some time in learning the core graphics. Please do share if you have any good tutorials. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a firm believer in learning through solving organic problems and slowly building my global knowledge on a subject. So I'm afraid I don't have any good tutorials for you.

Here is an example that will jump start you, though.

```
// For participating in Simulator's "slow animations"
@_silgen_name("UIAnimationDragCoefficient") func UIAnimationDragCoefficient() -> Float

import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class VerticalProgessView: UIControl {

    @IBInspectable
    var numberOfSegments: UInt = 0

    @IBInspectable
    var verticalSegmentGap: CGFloat = 4.0

    @IBInspectable
    var outerColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 33, green: 133, blue: 109)

    @IBInspectable
    var unfilledColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 61, green: 202, blue: 169)

    @IBInspectable
    var filledColor: UIColor = UIColor.white

    private var _progress: Float = 0.25
    @IBInspectable
    open var progress: Float {
        get {
            return _progress
        }
        set {
            self.setProgress(newValue, animated: false)
        }
    }

    let progressLayer = CALayer()

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    var skipLayoutSubviews = false

    open func setProgress(_ progress: Float, animated: Bool) {

        if progress < 0 {
            _progress = 0
        } else if progress > 1.0 {
            _progress = 1
        } else {
            // Clamp the percentage to discreet values
            let discreetPercentageDistance: Float = 1.0 / 28.0
            let nearestProgress = discreetPercentageDistance * round(progress/discreetPercentageDistance)

            _progress = nearestProgress
        }

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [weak self] in
            self?.skipLayoutSubviews = false
        }
        if !animated {
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        } else {
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.25 * Double(UIAnimationDragCoefficient()))
        }

        let properties = progressLayerProperties()
        progressLayer.bounds = properties.bounds
        progressLayer.position = properties.position

        skipLayoutSubviews = true
        CATransaction.commit() // This triggers layoutSubviews
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        self.layer.backgroundColor = unfilledColor.cgColor

        // Initialize and add the progressLayer
        let properties = progressLayerProperties()
        progressLayer.bounds = properties.bounds
        progressLayer.position = properties.position
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = filledColor.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)

        // Initialize and add the maskLayer (it has the holes)
        maskLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
        maskLayer.fillColor = outerColor.cgColor
        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        maskLayer.path = maskPath(for: maskLayer.bounds)
        self.layer.addSublayer(maskLayer)

        // Layer hierarchy

        // self.maskLayer
        // self.progressLayer
        // self.layer
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if skipLayoutSubviews {
            // Crude but effective, not fool proof though
            skipLayoutSubviews = false
            return
        }

        let timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        // Doesn't work for 180° rotations
        let duration = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration * Double(UIAnimationDragCoefficient())

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(timingFunction)
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)

        let properties = progressLayerProperties()
        progressLayer.bounds = properties.bounds
        progressLayer.position = properties.position

        let size = self.bounds.size

        let anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        maskLayer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint
        maskLayer.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        maskLayer.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * anchorPoint.x, y: size.height * anchorPoint.y)

        // Animate the segments

        let pathChangeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        let finalPath = maskPath(for: maskLayer.bounds)

        pathChangeAnimation.values = [maskLayer.path!, finalPath]
        pathChangeAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        pathChangeAnimation.timingFunction = timingFunction
        pathChangeAnimation.duration = duration
        pathChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        maskLayer.add(pathChangeAnimation, forKey: "pathAnimation")

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            // CAAnimation's don't actually change the value
            self.maskLayer.path = finalPath
        }

        CATransaction.commit()
    }

    // Provides a path that will mask out all the holes to show self.layer and the progressLayer behind
    private func maskPath(for rect: CGRect) -> CGPath {

        let horizontalSegmentGap: CGFloat = 5.0

        let segmentWidth = rect.width - horizontalSegmentGap * 2
        let segmentHeight = rect.height/CGFloat(numberOfSegments) - verticalSegmentGap + verticalSegmentGap/CGFloat(numberOfSegments)

        let segmentSize = CGSize(width: segmentWidth, height: segmentHeight)
        let segmentRect = CGRect(x: horizontalSegmentGap, y: 0, width: segmentSize.width, height: segmentSize.height)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {

            // Literally, just move it down by the y value here
            // this simplifies the math of calculating the starting points and what not
            let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 0, y: (segmentSize.height + verticalSegmentGap) * CGFloat(i))

            let segmentPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: segmentRect, cornerRadius: segmentSize.height / 2)
            segmentPath.apply(transform)

            path.addPath(segmentPath.cgPath)
        }

        // Without the outerPath, we'll end up with a bunch of squircles instead of a bunch of holes
        let outerPath = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil)

        path.addPath(outerPath)

        return path
    }

    /// Provides the current and correct bounds and position for the progressLayer
    private func progressLayerProperties() -> (bounds: CGRect, position: CGPoint) {
        let frame = self.bounds
        let height = frame.height * CGFloat(progress)
        let y = frame.height * CGFloat(1 - progress)
        let width = frame.width

        let anchorPoint = maskLayer.anchorPoint

        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        let position = CGPoint(x: 0 + width * anchorPoint.x, y: y + height * anchorPoint.x)

        return (bounds: bounds, position: position)
    }

    // TODO: Implement functions to further mimic UIProgressView
}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

#### Using in a storyboard

[image]

#### Enjoy the magic

[image]

Comment: You both are awesome and that was really quick. Just one small thing how do i slow down the animation? Thank you so so much for helping.

Comment: I've adjusted the code in my answer to allow adjustable animation duration. FYI, changing any animatable properties within a `CATransaction` will trigger an implicit animation. Inside that block, you can use any of the methods `CATransaction` offers, including disabling animations. :-)

Comment: @Paragon If you found this helpful, please accept ;-)

Comment: @Paragon I found that the code I provided did not handle the rotation animation very well. I've updated the code so it actually animates everything and stuff doesn't jump around in an unsightly fashion.

Answer (score 2):

So how you are doing it is fine.  Here would be two different ways.  The first with Core Graphics.  You may want to update methods and even make the color gradient in the sublayer.

1st Way

```
import UIKit

class Indicator: UIView {

    var padding : CGFloat = 5.0
    var minimumSpace : CGFloat = 4.0
    var indicators : CGFloat = 40
    var indicatorColor : UIColor = UIColor.lightGray
    var filledIndicatorColor = UIColor.blue

    var currentProgress = 0.0
    var radiusFactor : CGFloat = 0.25
    var fillReversed = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp(animated: false)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUp(animated: false)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    func updateProgress(progress:Double, animated:Bool) {
        currentProgress = progress
        setUp(animated: animated)
    }

    private func setUp(animated:Bool){

        // internal space
        let neededPadding = (indicators - 1) * minimumSpace
        //calculate height and width minus padding and space since vertical
        let height = (bounds.height - neededPadding - (padding * 2.0)) / indicators
        let width = bounds.width - padding * 2.0

        if animated == true{
            let trans = CATransition()
            trans.type = kCATransitionFade
            trans.duration = 0.5
            self.layer.add(trans, forKey: nil)
        }
        layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
        for i in 0...Int(indicators - 1.0){
            let indicatorLayer = CALayer()
            indicatorLayer.frame = CGRect(x: padding, y: CGFloat(i) * height + padding + (minimumSpace * CGFloat(i)), width: width, height: height)
            //haha i don't understand my logic below but it works hahaha
            // i know it has to go backwards
            if fillReversed{
                if CGFloat(1 - currentProgress) * self.bounds.height < indicatorLayer.frame.origin.y{
                    indicatorLayer.backgroundColor = filledIndicatorColor.cgColor
                }else{
                    indicatorLayer.backgroundColor = indicatorColor.cgColor
                }
            }else{
                if CGFloat(currentProgress) * self.bounds.height > indicatorLayer.frame.origin.y{
                     indicatorLayer.backgroundColor = indicatorColor.cgColor
                }else{
                    indicatorLayer.backgroundColor = filledIndicatorColor.cgColor

                }
            }

            indicatorLayer.cornerRadius = indicatorLayer.frame.height * radiusFactor
            indicatorLayer.masksToBounds = true
            self.layer.addSublayer(indicatorLayer)
        }
    }

    //handle rotation
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setUp(animated: false)
    }
}
```

The second way is using CAShapeLayer and the benefit is that the progress will get a natural animation.

```
    import UIKit

class Indicator: UIView {

    var padding : CGFloat = 5.0
    var minimumSpace : CGFloat = 4.0
    var indicators : CGFloat = 40
    var indicatorColor : UIColor = UIColor.lightGray
    var filledIndicatorColor = UIColor.blue

    var currentProgress = 0.0
    var radiusFactor : CGFloat = 0.25
    private var progressLayer : CALayer?
    private var shapeHoles : CAShapeLayer?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        transparentDotsAndProgress()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        transparentDotsAndProgress()
    }

    func updateProgress(progress:Double) {
        if progress <= 1 && progress >= 0{
            currentProgress = progress
            transparentDotsAndProgress()
        }
    }

    //handle rotation
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        transparentDotsAndProgress()
    }

    func transparentDotsAndProgress(){
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let neededPadding = (indicators - 1) * minimumSpace
        //calculate height and width minus padding and space since vertical
        let height = (bounds.height - neededPadding - (padding * 2.0)) / indicators
        let width = bounds.width - padding * 2.0

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height), cornerRadius: 0)
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        for i in 0...Int(indicators - 1.0){
            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: padding, y: CGFloat(i) * height + padding + (minimumSpace * CGFloat(i)), width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: height * radiusFactor)
            path.append(circlePath)
        }


        if progressLayer == nil{
            progressLayer = CALayer()
            progressLayer?.backgroundColor = filledIndicatorColor.cgColor
            self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer!)

        }

        progressLayer?.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: -self.bounds.height - padding + CGFloat(currentProgress) * self.bounds.height, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)


        self.shapeHoles?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        shapeHoles = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeHoles?.path = path.cgPath
        shapeHoles?.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        shapeHoles?.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeHoles?.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.backgroundColor = indicatorColor.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeHoles!)


    }

}
```

Both of these ways should work but the advantage of the CAShapeLayer is you get a natural animation.